# regular expression for dicom age

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to create regular expression.
There is an age, that can be written in the number of ways:

e.g. for person 64 years old it could be:

- 064Y
- 064
- 64

but for 0 years old it could also be

- 0Y
- 0

Could you help me producing right regular for JAVA matcher, so I can get Integer after parsing this the age string.

Currently I came to the following, which obviously does not cover all the possible cases.

```
  @Test
  public void testAgeConverter() throws AppException, IOException {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("0([0-9]+|[1-9]+)[Yy]?");

    Matcher m = pattern.matcher("062Y");
    String str = "";
    if (m.find()) {
      for (int i = 1; i <= m.groupCount(); i++) {
        str += "\n" + m.group(i);
      }
    }

    System.out.println(str);

  }
```

I will appreciate your help, thank you.

Comment: Can there be multiple `0s` before first digit? Is `00064Y` valid?

Comment: Anyone suggesting an answer should ensure that the leading zeros are not included in the match, since a number with a leading zero will be parsed as an octal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try with the following self-contained example:

```
String[] testCases = {
        "064Y", "064", "64", "0Y", "0"
};
int[] expectedResults = {
        64, 64, 64, 0, 0
};
//                           ┌ optional leading 0
//                           | ┌ 1 or 2 digits from 0 to 9 (00->99)
//                           | | in group 1
//                           | |           ┌ optional one Y
//                           | |           |    ┌ case insensitive
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("0*([0-9]{1,2})Y?", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
// fine-tune the Pattern for centenarians 
// (up to 199 years in this ugly draft): 
// "0*([0-1][0-9]{1,2}";
for (int i = 0; i < testCases.length; i++) {
    Matcher m = p.matcher(testCases[i]);
    if (m.find()) {
        System.out.printf("Found: %s%n", m.group());
        int result = Integer.parseInt(m.group(1));
        System.out.printf("Expected result is: %d, actual result is: %d", expectedResults[i], result);
        System.out.printf("... matched? %b%n", result == expectedResults[i]);
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
Found: 064Y
Expected result is: 64, actual result is: 64... matched? true
Found: 064
Expected result is: 64, actual result is: 64... matched? true
Found: 64
Expected result is: 64, actual result is: 64... matched? true
Found: 0Y
Expected result is: 0, actual result is: 0... matched? true
Found: 0
Expected result is: 0, actual result is: 0... matched? true
```

Comment: Good, but use `[0-9]{1,3}`, centagenarians aren't that uncommon (or `[0-9]+` to allow for future medical advances :).

Comment: @TimPietzcker good point. Let's have some hope around here :D

Comment: @TimPietzcker although, after thought, not sure what the criterium would be. 100 years? 110?

Comment: Someone could be over 100, I'd guess.

Comment: `Y*` is not correct you can match any number of Y's

Comment: thank you for very prompt answer, I finally end up using [0-9]{1,3}  ... but general idea was great and simple, thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

In any case, you only want the numbers so you could use

```
[0]*((\d)*)
```

Note that to make it work in `Java` you have to escape the `backslash` so

```
[0]*((\\d)*)
```

Then just capture the first matching group.

Which would select all the numbers, except the leading zeros. In the case of `0` or `0Y` it would select nothing but then you could check it easily with

```
if(result.isEmpty())
  val =  0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try and use something like so: `^0*?(\d+)Y?$`. A working example is available [here](https://regex101.com/r/cU6xN0/1). You would then iterate over the matches and use regex groups to extract the integer value you are after.

Answer (score 0):

Why is your expression so complicated? Won't this do...?

```
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([0-9]+)[Yy]?");

    Matcher m = pattern.matcher("062Y");
    Integer age = null;
    if (m.find()) {
        age = Integer.valueOf(m.group(1));
    }

    System.out.println(age);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to be more specific with the regex for the problem it can be solved with:

```
[0-9]+[Y|y]?
```

But this won't help you much you should try and narrow it down more with unique identifiers around these values

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `matcher.find`, it is not even necessary to match the leading zero; neither to match for `[yY]`, thus we have:

```
(1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])
```

which will find all the integers from 0 to 199 and give them in a group